# Get the coordinate of click inside iframe (pdf)

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

I display pdf documents in an iframe on my website (all documents are stored in the same domain).

I would like users to be able to click in the document to add comments at a specific location.
To do this, I am looking for a way to get the coordinate inside of an iframe (when we click).

It does not seem possible... However, there are paid solutions that offer this kind of functionality. Example : https://pdfjs.express/demo
So, what process is used?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: They read the PDF documents and render them in `<canvas>` elements. I assume they convert the renders back to PDF documents after the user is finished with modifiying them.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Great thanks, does this mean that with the "viewer" version of their solution, I could retrieve the coordinates myself and integrate this feature into my website for free?
Because, when I try to get the coordinate in their demo pdf it does not work (and it seems to be embed as an iframe)

Comment: I don't know. Try asking your question at their [support forum](https://pdfjs.community/c/technical-support/7). I'm sure they will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinate of a click using the `onmousedown` event. The event gives you a `MouseEvent` object that contains the `x` and `y` coordinate of the click relative to the view port.

To get the coordinate relative to your `iframe` you have to subtract `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`

[Example](https://codepen.io/Habetuz/pen/dyZzZQJ)

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe")

onmousedown = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("position").textContent = "Mouse position: " + (e.clientX - iframe.offsetLeft) + " | " + (e.clientY - iframe.offsetTop)
}
```

**Edit**

You could use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and a `canvas` instead of a simple `iframe` to better controll the PDF-viewer.

Comment: While that seems straightforward, it is totally unclear if that would yield what you want ... namely the PDF coordinates. This would have to account for page, scrolling, zoom and conversion to PDF coordinate space.

Comment: @KevinBrown I agree that this answer does not cover all use cases, but I also think that the question does not have enough information to give a better answer (without getting too complicated). I am happy to adapt my answer if the question author defines the problem better.